# Implementing a Graphical Diagram Editor -> What to choose? WPF? or

Tags: c#, wpf, graphics, object, diagram

I'm developing a kind of Graphical free activity diagram/circuit editor. I have to make it with C# or C++. I prefer C# though. What do you suggest I should use? Should I use the WPF (Windows Presentation Foundation)? or just add the presentation namespace to a normal Windows Application project or do you suggest a different method. I need to be able to implement a canvas like editor that users can drop objects and move and rotate and scale them. The objects are probably going to be just PNG images or something like that. I have never worked with WPF before but it seems good. It would be excellent if we could save the whole canvas in XML format.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WPF is very advanced GUI framework, it gives more flexibility and also you can look for find Visual Studio Domain Specific Language tools, that already has lot of functionality inbuilt to create a good Diagram editor in both WPF as well as Winforms.

Check out [Domain Specific Language Tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bb126235(v=VS.80).aspx)